# Haskell logbase error

Tags: haskell, logarithm, rounding-error

I am trying to calculate the length of an Integer in Haskell, using the fact that the length is equal to `truncate (log10(x)+1)`.

Using Integers I created:

```
len :: Integer -> Integer
len i = toInteger (truncate (logBase 10 (fromIntegral i)) + 1)
```

Unfortunately, not all numbers get the correct length. I tried a few different cases and found that:

```
logBase 10 10         = 1.0
logBase 10 100        = 2.0
logBase 10 1000       = 2.9999..6
logBase 10 10000      = 4.0
logBase 10 100000     = 5.0
logBase 10 1000000    = 5.9999999
```

Is there a reason why `logBase 10 1000` doesn't return 3.0? How do I get the correct log-value for 1000 in base 10?

Comment: `logBase` is defined as `log y / log x`; the division is probably the culprit, as while the `log` will be correct (with regard to roundings), the division of them doesn't have to be.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz So there is no way to get the correct result? Tried using (log 1000) / (log 10), but still 2.99996. Guess that the log-values might be rounded down for 1000 and up for 10, thus it will be slightly smaller than 3.

Comment: Suppose `log` is not necessary, you could avoid floating point operation with repeatedly divide by 10 (and higher power of 10).

Comment: @Pphoenix The easiest way to get the correct result could be to use `numbers` package, and call `logBase 10 1000 :: BigFloat Prec50`, then round that into float or double. Easiest, but not necessarily the best.

Comment: If you don't need `Double` Floating precision then use `Float` type instead and it seems fine. Such as `logBase 10 (1000 :: Float)` would return `3.0` or functionally `logBase 10 . (fromInteger :: Integer -> Float) $ 1000` would do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an integer log base function in GHC modules which has type `Integer -> Integer -> Int#`.

Example usage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import Control.Monad
import GHC.Integer.Logarithms ( integerLogBase# )
import GHC.Exts (Int(..))

main = do
  forM_ [(1::Int)..20] $ \n -> do
    let a = 10^n-1
        la = I# (integerLogBase# 10 a)
        b = 10^n
        lb = I# (integerLogBase# 10 b)
    putStrLn $ show a ++ " -> " ++ show la
    putStrLn $ show b ++ " -> " ++ show lb
```

Output:

```
9 -> 0
10 -> 1
99 -> 1
100 -> 2
999 -> 2
1000 -> 3
9999 -> 3
10000 -> 4
99999 -> 4
100000 -> 5
999999 -> 5
1000000 -> 6
9999999 -> 6
...
9999999999999999999 -> 18
10000000000000000000 -> 19
99999999999999999999 -> 19
100000000000000000000 -> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `Double` Floating precision then use `Float` type instead and it seems fine. Such as `logBase 10 (1000 :: Float)` would return `3.0` or functionally `logBase 10 . (fromInteger :: Integer -> Float) $ 1000` would do the same.

As per your code `toInteger` seems redundant since `truncate :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b` already does that job. So may simply do like

```
len :: Integer -> Integer
len = (+1) . truncate . logBase 10 . (fromIntegral :: Integer -> Float)
```

This will work correctly up until 9999987.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just go

```
amountOfDigits = length . show
```

(if you only interested in amount of digits in traditional base 10)

Comment: This would fail for numbers with leading zeros.

Answer (score -1):

```
len :: Integer -> Integer
len x
  | x <= 1 = 1 -- doesn't handle negative numbers
  | otherwise = ceiling (logBase 10 (fromIntegral x :: Float))
```