# Haskell if else list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm trying to print out a board in the right way, like this:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  
 1.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 2.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 3.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 4.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 5.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 6.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 7.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 8.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
 9.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
10.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
11.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
12.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
13.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
14.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
15.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
16.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
17.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .         
18.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

I have the list comprehension here

```
 ((concat [(""++show i)++"   " | i <- [1..n], i<10])++"\n")
```

I can get the 9 first numbers correctly, but the problem comes when i would like to put an else statement in my comprehension. I can't seem to know how to do that. So to make my self extra clear, i would like to do the same thing with the double digits but the only difference will be that i want two spaces instead of three between each double digit.

Comment: cause if i < 10 then "three spaces" else "two spaces", and i'm new to haskell so i don't know what you mean by intercalate. I'm doing my best with what I know.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try `if i<10 then "three spaces" else "two spaces"`?

Comment: I can't do it, I need to write it in this way. Is it even possible to write an else statement in a list comprehension?

Comment: Why not, a list comprehension is `[ <expr> | <list monad> ]` so you can write any valid Haskell regex.

Comment: so the form would be [<expr> | <list monad> | <expr> | <list monad>] ?

Comment: @ruubel: no, for instance `[ if <bool-expr> then <expr> else <expr> | <list-monad>]`

Comment: To find out how many spaces to deduct your best friend is a `floor . logBase 10 $ n` here. But check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26844123/4543207) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand of the list comprehension accepts any Haskell expression, so we can write the `if`-`then`-`else` in the left hand of the list comprehension and omit the `i < 10` condition on the right hand:

```
concat [(""++show i)++if i < 10 then "   " else "  " | i <- [1..n]]++"\n"
```

For `n = 15`, this then produces:

```
Prelude> concat [(""++show i)++if i < 10 then "   " else "  " | i <- [1..n]]++"\n"
"1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  \n"
```

We can also remove the `""++` part on the left side of the list comprehension, since this is bascially a *no operation*:

```
concat [show i ++ if i < 10 then "   " else "  " | i <- [1..n]] ++ "\n"
```

The above is however not very elegant: if `i = 123`, then we still will run into trouble. We can calculate the length of the `show`, calculate `4-l` (with `l` the length), and add this as extra spacing. For instance:

```
concat [s ++ replicate (4-length s) ' ' | i <- [1..n], let s = show i] ++ "\n"
```

There are also some more dedicated formatting and joining functions, but since the exercise is probably to get familier with lists, I think this is out of scope here.

Like @4castle says, we can use for instance `printf`:

```
import Text.Printf(printf)

concatMap (printf "%-4d") [1..n] ++ "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. It gave me a better understanding too.

Comment: By "dedicated formatting" are you referring to `printf "%-4d" i`?

Comment: @4castle: yes indeed, although there are of course more sophisticated tools.

Comment: @4castle: I added your suggestion to the answer.